# How to stabilise the matrix that denotes a $\frac{\pi}{2}$ turn around the z-axis?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Consider the i/s/o system:

$
\left\{
 \begin{array}{lll}
  \frac{d}{dt}x = Ax + Bu  \\
  y = Cx \\
         u = Ky 
 \end{array}
\right.$

If $A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix} 
$ and $B = (0 \quad 0 \quad 0)^{\intercal}$, which means there is no feedback in this, case, we know that the system is unstable because the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_{A} (t) = (t-1)(t+i)(t-i)$, which means there is an eigenvalue $t^{*} = 1 > 0$. I want to choose the vectors $B$ and $C$ in such a way that there is a $K$ such that the system becomes stable. I've tried many $B$ and $C$ before, but so far I haven't been able to find them in such a way that I can choose a $K$ that makes the system stable again.

For example, consider the example in which $B = (1 \quad 0 \quad 0)^{\intercal}$ and $C = (1 \quad 0 \quad 0)$. Then we have $y = Cx = (1 \quad 0 \quad 0)x$, so $u = Ky = (K \quad 0 \quad 0)$. This means we get $\frac{d}{dt} x = Ax + Bu = \begin{pmatrix}
K & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} x = Qx $

If we compute the characteristic polynomial, we find $P_{Q} (t) = t^{3} + (-1-K)t^{2} + (1+K)t - 1 = (t-1)(t- \frac{1}{2}(K - \sqrt{k^{2} - 4}))(t - \frac{1}{2}(K + \sqrt{k^{2} - 4})) $. This still has the eigenvalue $t^{*} = 1 > 0$. The system remains unstable, for whatever value of $K$ I choose.

I would like to see an example of vectors $C$ and $B$ such that I **can** make the system stable again, given the matrix $A$ above. I don't care what the value of $K$ is, as long as there is **some** $K$ which makes the system that was once unstable, now stable again.

Can you give me an example of this?

Comment: I think you made a typo in your expression for $A$. Because everything else in your question seems to indicate that $A_{33}$ should be $1$ instead of $-1$. Also you said that $u=K\,y=\begin{pmatrix}K & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, but I assume that should have been $u=K\,y=\begin{pmatrix}K & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\,x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose for example $B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $C = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Taking now $u = -Kx$ with $K = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ places all three eigenvalues at $-1$.

Btw. the eigenvalues of your (uncontrolled) $A$ matrix are actually $\color{red}{-1}$, $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: Thank you! You're right. Shouldn't $K \in \mathbb{R}$  though? Instead of $K \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 3}$ ?

Comment: No. You compute the controlled matrix like $A_c = A - B\cdot K$. Therefore $K \in \mathbb{R}$ would mean you subtract a $3 \times 1$ vector from a $3 \times 3$ matrix which cannot work. The system itself is SISO (single input, single output) but nethertheless you can give different weight to $u$ to affect each state different. This is expressed by the vector $K \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 3}$.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can choose $B$ and $C$, so you can view your problem as finding a state feedback law with,

$$
\dot{x} = A\,x + B\,u, \tag{1}
$$

$$
u = -K\,C\,x = -\hat{K}\,x, \tag{2}
$$

such that $A - \hat{K}$ is Hurwitz.

But this can only be the case if $(A,B)$ is controllable or at least stabilizable. You could check for this using the [controllability matrix](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Controllability_and_Observability#Controllability_Matrix) or the [Hautus test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma) for all eigenvalues of $A$ to test for controllability or only the eigenvalues with a positive real part to test for stabilizability.

You could also consider to use a [similarity transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimilarityTransformation.html) and bring $A$ in to the form needed for the [controllable canonical form](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Standard_Forms#Controllable_Canonical_Form). Namely in this form the $a_i$ terms represent all the negative coefficients (except the highest power) of the characteristic polynomial.

And finally I would like to note that your $A$ matrix is in the [real Jordan form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices) and that only the bottom right Jordan block has a positive real eigenvalue, which should be controlled to make the system stable.